# ERROR: Error accessing files to attach: Expecting Ant GLOB pattern

Tags: linux, jenkins, ant, email-ext

I'm getting an error while attaching a file to the mail post Jenkins job.

```
ERROR: Error accessing files to attach: Expecting Ant GLOB pattern, but saw '/Test/reports/test_report.html' See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html for syntax
```

Comment: You should mark this question as resolved I think

Answer (score 4):

Just a workaround, copy the file from its location to $WORKSPACE

```
cp $WORKSPACE/Test/reports/test_report.html $WORKSPACE/test_report.html
```

and just specify "test_report.html" in attachment field of your jenkins.

Comment: or rather move it instead of copying.